# Replace values in column based on key value pair

Tags: r, key-value

I have a data frame where the last column is used to label a plot. The column is mostly NAs, but has 12 values in it (matches the key in the list below). However, the label is wrong and needs replacing to match other plots I have (i.e. replace with the value in the list below). The label is placed on the most recent date.

```
labels <- list('HM SSSI 1'= 'SSSI 1',
               'HM SSSI 2' = 'SSSI 2',
               'HM SSSI 3' = 'SSSI 3',
               'HM SSSI 4' = 'SSSI 4',
               'HMB 1'= 'B1',
               'HMB 2'= 'B2',
               'HMB 3'= 'B3',
               'HMB 4'= 'B4',
               'HMB 5'= 'B5',
               'HMB 6'= 'B6',
               'HMB 7'= 'B7',
               'HMB 8'= 'B8')
```

This is the code used to generate the current label:

```
allfilesGround_long$label <- NA
allfilesGround_long$label[which(allfilesGround_long$Date == max(allfilesGround_long$Date))] <- 
  allfilesGround_long$Location[which(allfilesGround_long$Date == max(allfilesGround_long$Date))]
```

This is what the table looks like when I sort by the label column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an atomic vector of keys-values instead of a list, like this:

```r
# key-values
dico <- c(
  "HMB 1" = "B1",
  "HMB 2" = "B2"
)
# the vector you want to transform
labels <- c("HMB 1", "HMB 2", NA)
# the transformed vector
dico[labels]
```

Comment: How does this work with the column in the dataframe?#

Comment: @MelanieBaker `df$label <- dico[df$label]`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `dplyr::recode` or perhaps even easier in your case to simply use `gsub` instead of manually creating a lookup table:

```r
set.seed(123)

allfilesGround_long <- data.frame(
  Location = sample(names(labels), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

allfilesGround_long$label <- dplyr::recode(allfilesGround_long$Location, !!!labels)

allfilesGround_long
#>     Location  label
#> 1  HM SSSI 3 SSSI 3
#> 2  HM SSSI 3 SSSI 3
#> 3      HMB 6     B6
#> 4  HM SSSI 2 SSSI 2
#> 5      HMB 2     B2
#> 6      HMB 7     B7
#> 7      HMB 1     B1
#> 8  HM SSSI 4 SSSI 4
#> 9      HMB 2     B2
#> 10     HMB 5     B5

allfilesGround_long$label2 <- gsub("^HM\\s?", "", allfilesGround_long$Location)
allfilesGround_long$label2 <- gsub("^B\\s", "B", allfilesGround_long$label2)

allfilesGround_long
#>     Location  label label2
#> 1  HM SSSI 3 SSSI 3 SSSI 3
#> 2  HM SSSI 3 SSSI 3 SSSI 3
#> 3      HMB 6     B6     B6
#> 4  HM SSSI 2 SSSI 2 SSSI 2
#> 5      HMB 2     B2     B2
#> 6      HMB 7     B7     B7
#> 7      HMB 1     B1     B1
#> 8  HM SSSI 4 SSSI 4 SSSI 4
#> 9      HMB 2     B2     B2
#> 10     HMB 5     B5     B5
```

Comment: I only need to fill the last date. Otherwise the ggplot gets confused with having too many labels.